# How do I use python to continually update the seconds of a timestamp on a page?

Tags: django, datetime, python-2.7, django-views

I currently have a test Django framework and in my views.py, I have:

```
def get_date_time(request):
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    # more date and time formatting code here...
    formatted_date = ...
    formatted_time = ...

    return render(request, "local_time.html", {"current_date": formatted_date, "current_time": formatted_time})
```

My time is formatted as HH:MM:SS.  In my templates, I have the `local_time.html` file in which I include `{{current_date}}` and `{{current_time}}` using the Django template syntax.

What I want, though, is the page to continually display the increasing seconds, instead of just a static string.  How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Just to be clear: do you want to create an HTML page that has a clock, which updates without page reloads?

Comment: Right.  I want an HTML page that displays MMDDYY and HH:MM:SS. Without refreshing the page, the viewer can see the seconds ticking, the minutes progressing and so on...

Comment: Django is a backend framework. If you want to do stuff in the frontend, consider using JavaScript.

Comment: That makes sense.  However, I tried making a separate Javascript file and referencing it within my HTML template as `<script src="js/mydatetime.js" ...></script>` and nothing shows up.  Not, even `alert`.  My server is hosting my site at `http://localhost/time/` and when I include that `script` tag, and refresh the page, it's trying to pull the Javascript files from `http://localhost/time/js/mydatetime.js`.  Why is this?

Comment: That's another different problem, you need to properly setup your statics etc etc etc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, in order to serve Javascript, CSS, image files and static files from a purely developmental standpoint using Django, refer to this article:

[How to Serve Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/)

For production, you would obviously have to use a web server like Apache.

Answer (score 1):

For continuously updating timer, you need to write JavaScript. The practical problem you are facing with it, is that you need to make sure the script is loaded from the correct location. For this, try:

```
<script src="/js/mydatetime.js" ...></script>
```

Comment: By adding a slash in front of the path, I now see that my server's GET request is looking for `http://localhost/js/mydatetime.js` which does not exist.  I'm guessing that the javascript should run client-side and continuously poll the server for info and then display it with HTML.  My HTML file is a template that links to the Django views.py if that helps at all.  I also set my URLconf to hook `/time/` to the appropriate view.

Comment: Well, JavaScript does run on the client-side. You definitely need to either poll the server continuously for updates, or simply write a JavaScript function that updates the timer continuously - you don't need server polling to count seconds.

Comment: True, but within my Django view, I've used the Python `datetime` module to get and format the appropriate date and time.  I also tried adding a script to my HTML but for some reason that seems to ask Django to look in its directory structure for a js file.

Comment: OK I think I get the point. Django does not "load" the JavaScript file, it serves it to the browser, which further loads and executes the contained script.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm still struggling with my problem on how to get my javascripts to run.  I'm doing a simple `alert` and on FireFox, my captures tell me that it is failing to find `GET http://localhost/js/mydatetime.js HTTP/1.1` and `GET http://localhost/time/js/mydatetime.js HTTP/1.1` depending on whether or not I have a slash in front of my script tag src.

Comment: Thanks for your help jsalonen.  I managed to get it working by using this article: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/  Moderators can close this topic or mark as resolved.